# Trouble understanding Xcode Swift files and Struct Class declarations

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning Swift and SwiftUI at the same time.  I have some programming experience but my background is functional programming so OOP is still new to me. I've watched and followed several videos from coders on SwiftUI and I feel the use of Controls and modifiers makes sense.  As I get ready to build an app however, I thought it would make sense to build my data structure in it's own Swift File (as a struct) and then instantiate it and pass that "test data" to my ContentView so I could work on and see how to build out the view the way I wanted.  The confusion at the moment is trying to understand is WHERE should I define my data model and WHERE do I instantiate it and populate it with data, then how to pass it to my content view.  I hope this is making sense.  If I have a separate file PlayerView.swift and define my struct there for a "Player" and then declare a variable testdata = PlayerView() and then populate testdata.name = "Stephen" for example is testdata GLOBAL to the rest of the swift environment.  Again, having it as a separate file is confusing to me as I don't understand the global / variable scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK First thing first - what you are looking for is Modeling you structure. So I would suggest to look into MVC first and when you completely understand MVC then look for MVVM

MVC - Model View Controller Pattern

View -  PlayerView -  here you should have all view related methods

Model : make PlayerModel - create your struct "Player"

Controller - initiate your model or in your words "declare a variable testdata = PlayerView()"

After you completely understand this model then try learning about MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Structures and classes are good choices for storing data and modeling behavior in your apps, but their similarities can make it difficult to choose one over the other.

when adding a new data type to your app :

- Use structures by default.
- Use classes when you need Objective-C interoperability.
- Use classes when you need to control the identity of the data you're
  modeling.
- Use structures along with protocols to adopt behavior by sharing
  implementations.

Structs can include stored properties, computed properties, and methods. Moreover, Swift structures can adopt protocols to gain behavior through default implementations. The Swift standard library and Foundation use structures for types you use frequently, such as numbers, strings, arrays, and dictionaries.

**When do We need use Class**

> If you use an Objective-C API that needs to process your data, or you
>   need to fit your data model into an existing class hierarchy defined
>   in an Objective-C framework, you might need to use classes and class
>   inheritance to model your data. For example, many Objective-C
>   frameworks expose classes that you are expected to subclass.

or when we need to control an identity we use class for modeling data.  classes are still considered to be different by the identity operator (===). It also means that when you share a class instance across your app, changes you make to that instance are visible to every part of your code that holds a reference to that instance.
For example, if you have a type that represents a local database connection, the code that manages access to that database needs full control over the state of the database as viewed from your app. It's appropriate to use a class in this case, but be sure to limit which parts of your app get access to the shared database object.

**When do we need to use Struct**

- Use structures when you're modeling data that contains information
  about an entity with an identity that you don't control.
- Use Structures and Protocols to Model Inheritance and Share Behavior

  Structures and protocols can only adopt protocols, they can't inherit from classes.

refer [Choosing Between Structures and Classes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes)

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, the usual approach is to write the model data class as an ObservableObject and inject it into your app's Environment so that it is available to all view structs.

Comment: Good tutorial here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views